# Log4Net UDP doesn't log from MVC applications

Tags: c#, log4net

I have some NServiceBus endpoints hosted as Windows Services and a few MVC 5 web sites in the same solution. All the projects use the same Assembly configuration for log4net and the same config file (literally the same files, they are shared files). The desired output is the UDP appender output to a Log2Console session.
The windows services log everything fine, but the MVC web sites do not.

Here is the assembly config:

`[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4netconfig.xml", Watch = true)]`

And here is the content of "log4netconfig.xml":

```
<log4net>
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender" >
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
    <remoteAddress value="127.0.0.1" />
    <remotePort value="9998" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j" />
</appender>
<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="UdpAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</root>
</log4net>
```

**Edit**

After removing the assembly config attribute, adding a log statement as the first item in Application_Start and setting up the below in web.config, I still get no logging:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender" >
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
      <remoteAddress value="127.0.0.1" />
      <remotePort value="9998" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j" />
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="UdpAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: Assuming this isn't a permissions issue, note that when using assembly attributes, ["it is imperative to make a logging call as early as possible during the application start-up, and certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked"](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#attributes) - do you have this in your MVC sites, for example in `Application_Start`?

Comment: This seems to be a clear case of RTFM. I wasn't aware of this.
I tried the application_start thingie, but still no luck. I will change a web application to use configuration from web.config instead of the assembly attribute to see if that helps.

Comment: Even though you've moved the config into the web config file, you still need to initialise log4net, via a call to `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` - the logging call in start is to initialise the log system when loaded by the assembly attribute. You can still have your config in a separate file and use [the Configure overload that takes a FileInfo](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure_overload_5.html)